# Am I sending and receiving messages using AWS SQS FIFO queue correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am in the process of investigating AWS SQS FIFO queues and building some prototype. I am however having difficulty in grasping how I can extract a specific message that was sent.
A couple of questions now:

1. I understand that with the `ReceiveMessageAsync` call, a list of messages is being returned. Should I loop through this list and match the `MessageId` property with that of my original sent message?
2. If there is a list of unprocessed messages in the queue, lets say 15, and I send a new message, will my message only be returned with `ReceiveMessageAsync` when at least 6 messages are deleted off the queue?

Currently in my prototype, I perform a `SendMessageAsync` request and immediately afterwards, perform a `ReceiveMessageAsync` in order to get the processed message. It is here that I loop through the received list of messageIds in order to get my message, perform some logic on the message, and then request to delete the message off the queue. Is this logic correct?

```
var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            var sendQueueUrl = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSServer"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQSSend"]}";
            var deduplicationId = "fc1e026d-4a04-4cdf-b0b0-16bc78dde19c"; //Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var sqsMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest
        {
            QueueUrl = sendQueueUrl,
            MessageGroupId = "testGroup",
            MessageDeduplicationId = deduplicationId,
            MessageBody = "{\"message\":\"hello\"}"
        };
        try
        {
            var sendMessageResponse = await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(sqsMessageRequest);

            var receiveQueueUrl = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSServer"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQSReceive"]}";
            var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                AttributeNames = { "All" },
                MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,
                MessageAttributeNames = { "All" },
                QueueUrl = receiveQueueUrl,
                WaitTimeSeconds = 20
            };

            bool messagesFound = false;

            while (!messagesFound)
            {
                var receiveMessageResponse = await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);

                if (receiveMessageResponse.HttpStatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed request to receive message\n");
                else
                {
                    foreach (var message in receiveMessageResponse.Messages)
                    {
                        if (message.MessageId != sendMessageResponse.MessageId)
                            continue;

                        messagesFound = true;
                        /*process message further and delete afterwards*/
                        var deleteMessageRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest($"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSServer"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQSReceive"]}", message.ReceiptHandle);
                        var deleteMessageResponse = await sqsClient.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteMessageRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("SendMessageAsync: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqsClient.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: _WHY_ do you want to "extract a specific message that was sent"? That does not fit with the normal way that a queue is used. Can you tell us more about your overall process and why a specific message might be required?

Comment: So for my prototype, I wanted to receive an updated message back from the queue, right after I sent it. There is a consumer that processes and updates the message on their side and then updates the queue with the processed message, after which I wanted to display the message.

Comment: Can you provide information about the bigger-picture of your system? What do you mean by "their side"? Will there be lots of messages sent to queues for processing? Why are you using a queue if you want a specific message to be processed, rather than just taking the next message off a queue? If you can explain more about your end-goals (rather than implementation details), we might be able to offer an alternative solution.

Comment: A user on a system performs an update of some details, which sends a "update" message to the queue (user is waiting for a response in order to continue). That message is received by another system that needs to perform the data update and provide an updated message back to the producer. That updated message can contain any type of info (failed/successful update indication, new info, etc.) The producer system receives the specific "update" message back and the user can continue on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over a queue to find a specific item will be inefficient for SQS in a FIFO queue if this is your aim.

You would actually be better looking at [Virtual Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-temporary-queues.html) which will offer a way to use SQS to perform a 1 to 1 mapping of send and receive.

By using this feature, you would define a virtual queue for your specific message, the consumer will be able to process all messages (or technically consumer from a specific virtual queue).

Whereas both FIFO and standard SQS queues you will need to process all messages in the queue, which is capped to 10 messages at a time. This makes it really inefficient to try to find your specific message.

Comment: Sure, I understand. You are indeed correct that the messages should be processed, each to its own.

Comment: No problem, hope this helped :)